# fileinputstream throwing filenotfoundexception while trying to retrieve a bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to retrieve a bitmap from internal memory but it works on older versions , not on newer versions of android.It throws a filenotfoundexception.

The code which i use is:

```
public Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context context,String name){
        //BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        try{
//          FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
//            File file = new File("filesdir", name);
              File myFile = new File (path_file+File.separator+name); 
            //byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
             //bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                //fis.close();
                return b;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
          finally{
              if(fis!=null)
              {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }

          }

        }
```

The fileinputstream object `fis` throws a filenotfoundexception.please help!!

Comment: An example of the path that you are giving to `fis` might be helpful. The path may not be properly formatted, which is causing the exception. (Also, check if the file is actually there, but I'm assuming you already did that.)

Comment: What is `path_file`? What is `name`? Why are you using string concatenation rather than the appropriate `File` constructor? What is the full path that is failing with the `FileNotFoundException`? Why are you catching `Exception e` and then doing nothing?

Comment: The above code works fine on older android 2.6 but fails on new androdi 4+

Comment: I am calling the method as Bitmap obj=getImageBitmap(MainActivity.this,s.category+".png");               path_file=MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 0):

okay y you commented `BufferedInputStream`
use it like this

```
File myFile = new File ( path+ File.separator + fname); 
                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

change variable names as peryour program

Comment: what is the value of path_file

Comment: path_file=MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

Comment: WHy does it work fine on older devices.But fails on newer ones?

Comment: What about the close method?

Comment: what close method??  if you are talking about  fis.close(); than i suggest you to remove finally block